# Java regex for logging messages

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I want to match logging messages like

```
19:43:09.469 [main] INFO  o.g.s.logging.HashCodeConverterIT [1083962448] - message
```

and extract the number inside `[]` with a named group. Afaik

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d.\\d\\d\\d \\[main\\] INFO  o.g.s.logging.HashCodeConverterIT \\[(?<id>[0-9]+)\\] - message")
```

should deliver a pattern so that

```
p.matcher("19:43:09.469 [main] INFO  o.g.s.logging.HashCodeConverterIT [1083962448] - message").group("id")
```

returns `1083962448`. I verified that the regex is working with https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html which shows that `matches` is `true` and that the second group is the number I want to extract. However the OpenJDK 8 the retrieval fails due to  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` both for access with the group name and index `1`.

Comment: You need to escape '`.`' (dot) and, most likely, `':'` (colon) as well.

Comment: @PM77-1 there's no `,` in the question and `.` wouldn't cover up the described error. The question my question is a duplicate of provides the solution.